# Common causes of overheating cpu & hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, temperature

Wife's laptop is constantly registering higher than normal temperatures for the hard drive and cpu.

The fan is working, and is constantly running.

The temperatures for the hard drive and each core of the processor are running around 165 degrees Farenheit.

```
Hardware monitor    ACPI
    Temperature 0   74°C (165°F) [0xD90] (TZ00)
    Temperature 1   74°C (165°F) [0xD90] (TZ01)
```

What is the most common cause of this level of temperatures?

Case is clean; there doesn't seem to be any run way processes. The above temps are at idle.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant on ServerFault I'm afraid. That being said, it could be a single component that's causing it, I've had some issues with graphics cards in laptops. If possible remove some of the more likely culprits (such as secondary graphic cards, hard drives) and test the temperature to at least narrow your search.

Comment: 74°C for a CPU is normal.  There are two possibilities.  The sensor in question is only reporting the CPU temperature.  What does the HDD report its temperature as? A hdd overheating would be extremely odd.

Comment: @Ramhound: 74C **at idle** is definitely a cause for concern.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I see no mention of the load on the processor.  It isn't even clear if the temperature actually includes the HDD.  I have my suspicions that it doesn't.

Comment: @Ramhound: Reread the last line in the question.

Comment: Dumb question but just to eliminate the possibility: there's no potential environmental factor, like using it on your lap or a soft surface like a bed, and the bottom air vents getting blocked?

Comment: @fixer1234 - good question. My wife uses it 50/50 lap/desk. At time of taking the reading, I let it idle on a tabletop for 30 minutes to ensure the reading was accurate.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use `top` to check if you have a process that is keeping the CPU busy. If you are using Windows you have `Task Manager` also to check the same thing.

Comment: No process that's consuming the cpu. These temps are at idle.

Answer (score 0):

Bad airflow and a very busy computer. Very hard to say anything else about it without additional information.

Comment: see updates above.

Answer (score 0):

The most usual reason for that is that the cooling airflow is somehow being impeded, most likely due to dirt / dust in the intake grill and/or air conduit and/or CPU cooler gills. One more common cause is not enough clearance between the air intake grill (usually under the laptop) and the surface below (sometimes a lap), which blocks off the air flow.

Comment: *"Case is clean"* If the author is truthfully reporting the status of his case then dirt couldn't be the cause of the air flow problem.

Comment: case is clean… but fans & fins are dust-bunny hutches:) Hard to tell from the OP. If it's not been stripped in a year, now would be the time.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I haven't pulled it this year; only dust vacuum/blown air.

Answer (score 0):

just for anyone else who stumbles across this (I found it last week in top 10 on google with the same issue) only mine were way higher. Mine would hit 105C (240F) under 50% load and stay at around 60-70C at idle, took it in finally when I could afford it and ironically the hard drive was failing (which I had already suspected as it was making strange noises) and apparently pulling too much power and making the cpu over work somehow. after replacing the drive mine is sitting at 31C this very moment while typing this and maxes out around 65 under 100% load with cinebench. I still open hardware monitor just in case the tech was wrong but so far he's been right, I guess the failing drive was slowing the computer down and making the cpu work harder than task manager was showing. I'm not a tech and I still find it odd a bad drive can cause it to over heat but like I said hasn't over heated since changing the hard drive. mine is an Core i7 M620 which can run hotter but still 105C (240+F) is way hotter than it should have been. hope this helps someone in the future.